# Represenation of if logic in SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

Need help to represent the the logic in different way.There are 2 fields in opportunity Brokerage__c which is a lookup to account and Broker_Contact__c which is lookup to contact.
There is a piece of code where a condition in if loop should be included in SOQL query itself.

Below is the code

```
thisQuery = 'Select Id, name FROM Opportunity WHERE isClosed = false AND AND RecordTypeId IN:recordTypeIds  ORDER BY CloseDate ASC Limit :queryLimit offset :queryOffset';
    oppListFromDb=Database.query(thisQuery);
    system.debug('******'+oppListFromDb.size());
    for(Opportunity o :Database.query(thisQuery)){
        if(o.Brokerage__c==o.Broker_Contact__r.AccountId){
        tempOppRecordIds.add(o.Id);
    }
 }
```

I have to represent the following if loop comparison in SOQL  itself how can i do that?

Please guide me.

```
        if(o.Brokerage__c==o.Broker_Contact__r.AccountId)
```

Thanks.

Comment: If I am not wrong then no you can't do that in soql.

Comment: @Ratan Is there a alternative for this...Like dynamic soql or something which i might  not be aware of?

Comment: As far I know. no there is no way to compare same object field in same soql(dynamic or anything).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per documentation is is not supported. take a look at this: **[link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_fieldexpression.htm)**

> A value used to compare with the value in fieldName. You must supply a
>   value whose data type matches the field type of the specified field.
>   **You must supply a native value—other field names or calculations are
>   not permitted**. If quotes are required (for example, they are not for
>   dates and numbers), use single quotes. Double quotes result in an
>   error.

So the other alternative for you is to create a formula field that return Boolean value and then check if the value of formula in your SOQL.

```
thisQuery = 'Select Id, name FROM Opportunity WHERE isClosed = false AND RecordTypeId IN:recordTypeIds AND my_formula__= true ORDER BY CloseDate ASC Limit :queryLimit offset :queryOffset';
```

It seems that you want to optimize your code by moving that condition in where clause. If that is true then you may not get the objective served by moving it in where clause. I would suggest you to try and see query plan and then choose your option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this indirectly through a Formula Field , and then use that field in your query.

Say you have a Checkbox formula field on the Opportunity, `Broker_Contact_Matches__c`. The simplest formula to give you your result is this:

```
Brokerage__c = Broker_Contact__r.AccountId
```

Then your query can be

```
select Id,... 
from Opportunity 
where (other requirements) 
    AND Broker_Contact_Matches__c = TRUE
```

Comment: Your formula example is ...weird. `Brokerage__c = Broker_Contact__r.AccountId` is enough to return boolean

Comment: Your example is simpler for sure. Edited.